# Javascript array equality control

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hi I have two changeable length arrays and I tried If there is no value I want, delete it from that array

```
array1 = [
    {
      "serial": "3",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "700",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "300",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "400",
      "code": "1"
    }
]

array2 = [{
      "someting": 10,
      "someting2": "20",
      "serialList": ["700","711"],
    },

{
      "someting": 10,
      "someting2": "30",
      "serialList": ["300"],
    },
{
      "someting": 0,
      "someting2": "0",
      "serialList": [],
    }
]
```

this my two array as I said arrays length is changeable sometimes array1 length big, sometimes array2 and I want If serial number in array1 does not exist in array2 delete from array1 element, 
according to above array1[0] and array1[3] serial codes does not exist any element of array2 I want to output array1 is:

```
array1 = [
    {
      "serial": "700",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "300",
      "code": "1"
    }
]
```

How can I do that, thnx

Comment: here are some useful functions for your solution: [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Nina Scholtz can solve it in a blink of an eye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple and readable approach to achieve that

```js
let allowedSerials = array2.map( obj=> obj.serialList ).flat();
let result = array1.filter( obj =>  allowedSerials.includes(obj.serial) )
```

check the snippet below:

```js
let array1 = [
    {
      "serial": "3",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "700",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "300",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "400",
      "code": "1"
    }
]

let array2 = [{
      "someting": 10,
      "someting2": "20",
      "serialList": ["700","711"],
    },

{
      "someting": 10,
      "someting2": "30",
      "serialList": ["300"],
    },
{
      "someting": 0,
      "someting2": "0",
      "serialList": [],
    }
];

// straight-forward solution:
let allowedSerials = array2.map( obj=> obj.serialList ).flat();
let result = array1.filter( obj =>  allowedSerials.includes(obj.serial) )
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I would have one more question sorry about that my array1 = [
    {
      "serial": "3",
      "code": "1"
    },
    {
      "serial": "700",
      "code": "1"
    },
]

array2 = [{
      "someting": 10,
      "code": "3",
      "serialList": ["700","711"],
    },
]  
my arrays like that code is change how can I array1 output code value equal to array 2 same serials code new array1 output is like: array1 = [
    {
      "serial": "700",
      "code": "3"
    },
]

Comment: @Alisan26 so.. this requires a little modification to achieve that; btw you can ask it as a new question; thats legit

Comment: Im ask new question here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402967/javascript-array-equality-control-and-changing-value